# Change TextView after a certain amount of time for N number of times Android

Tags: android

I need to change a textview after 8.47 seconds 8 times and then change it 8 more times but only after 8.00 seconds.
Please help because I am unsure how to code this.

I have tried looking for code, but it hasn't helped on how to do this.
Here is what I have so far.

```
public class Twenty_Meter_Test extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Chronometer myChronometer;
int level = 1;
int shuttle = 1;
int updates = 0;
String levels = level + "." + shuttle;
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.levelcount);


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tweney__meter__test);

    myChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);

    (findViewById(R.id.start_twenty)).setOnClickListener(this);
    (findViewById(R.id.stop_twenty)).setOnClickListener(this);




}

public void onClick (View view) {
    textView.setText(levels);

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.start_twenty: {

            myChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            myChronometer.start();

            break;
        }
        case R.id.stop_twenty: {
            myChronometer.stop();
            break;
        }

    }
}

public void updateTextView () {
    if (updates < 8) {
        updates++;
        level++;
        textView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
        public void run() {
                level++;
                textView.setText(levels);
                updateTextView();
            }
        }, 8470);
    }
    level = 0;
    shuttle = 2;
    if (updates > 8 && updates < 16) {
        updates++;

        textView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                level++;
                updateTextView();
            }
        }, 8000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for `TimerTask`.  See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html

Comment: you can handlers and runnables also to add to @CzarMatt if you are to use timer task remember it works on a background task,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Chronometer, try this

*create global variables and objects

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private long timeUnformatted = 0L;
private long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
private long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
private long updatedTime = 0L;
```

*use runnable

```
private Runnable updateTimerMethod = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - timeUnformatted;
        updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

        seconds = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
        minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;
        ms = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);

        if (seconds == 8) {
            // do something
        }   
    }
};
```

In onCreate() to start timer add

```
mHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerMethod, 0);
```

To stop timer add

```
mHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerMethod);
```

In onPause() add

```
timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
mHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerMethod);
```

*In onResume() start the time again

Comment: I need it to count up not count down

Comment: I am trying to implement this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-stage_fitness_test

Comment: Do I need to have an onPause() method? Because I don't have one

Comment: Yes, so that if the app goes into the background you won't lose your time.

Comment: MY last question doesn't regard to this, but for mediaPlayer, it says I have incompatible types... This is what I have

Comment: public MediaPlayer shuttle;                                                                                shuttle = MediaPlayer.create(Twenty_Meter_Test.this, R.raw.shuttleSound);